# Forwarding from A Record's IP Address

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, cname-record, a-record

mycustomer.com has an A record with 11.11.11.11 IP.

I am the owner of the 11.11.11.11. The server uses Windows DNS.

When I create a forward zone with mycustomer.com and put an A record with the IP of 12.12.12.12.

It does not work.

I want to give an A record for the second time or how can I reforward the same domain to another IP from my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, and that is excepted. Your current understanding on how DNS works is incorrect; you cannot "give an A record for the second time".

An [`A` record](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.4.1) simply maps the name to an IP address (or multiple IP addresses for *round-robin* redundancy), and the DNS resolution is finished. It doesn't delegate control over the record to the server which it is pointing to – only an [`NS` record](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.3.11) would do that.